# Blazor - Templating Multi-Step Forms using Generic RenderFragment

Tags: c#, templates, generics, blazor

Looking into something at the moment that I believe should be possible using Blazor, but can't quite get a handle on how to implement it. Reaching out on here to see if I can get a nudge in the right direction.

A project I'm working on currently uses a number of multi-step forms (navigating between steps using forward and back buttons). These were initially handled case-by-case but, now that they're becoming increasingly widely-used, I'm looking to implement a generic solution where you can create a form wrapper (displaying title and handling navigation), and use a given list of forms to create the child content.

My initial idea was to use a `StepModel`, to hold the relevant information on each step:

```
public class StepModel
{
  public int StepNo { get; set; }
  public string FormTitle { get; set; }
  public bool CanSkip { get; set; }
  public RenderFragment? FormToRender { get; set; } //this prop is the sticking point of my issue 
}
```

The idea being that the parent page, containing the multi-step form, could have a list of `StepModel` instances that would drive the rendering of the various forms as you navigated:

```
//in FormParent.razor.cs

private static IEnumerable<StepModel> GetSteps()
{
  return new StepModel[]
  {
    new StepModel
    {
      StepNo = 1,
      FormTitle = "Step 1",
      CanSkip = true,
      FormToRender = //Can I pass a component definition for <FormStep1/> here?
    },
    new StepModel
    {
      StepNo = 2,
      FormTitle = "Step 2",
      CanSkip = true,
      FormToRender = //Can I pass a component definition for <FormStep2/> here?
    },
  }
}
```

I'm hoping that, with this approach, I can then do something like this in the `FormParent.razor` file:

```
//assume an index for the current form step
<div>
  Displaying Step @CurrentStepNo of @GetSteps().Count
<div>
<div>
  @foreach (var step in GetSteps())
  {
    @if (CurrentStepNo == step.StepNo)
    {
      step.FormToRender //can I render this here?
    }
  }
</div>
<div>
  // nav buttons 
</div>
```

Hope this is enough to go on, as I've tried to keep it to the relevant portions. If you guys think I'm close as to being able to achieve this, I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction with respect to how to use the `RenderFragment` properties.

If anyone thinks I'm way off and need to rethink, I'd appreciate any guidance in what might be a better approach.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Can you publish a MRE project to say Github with your code so far.  There are several approaches, but it's easy to go off on a tangent without a clearer view.  What does you edit model look like? Flat I hope, if not then an aggregate object of some type?.

Comment: Just for my understanding: There will be multiple Froms each with multiple steps. Thoose Frompages are supposed to inherit their basic makeup from FormParent, but thoose ChildForms will have different step definitions in their GetSteps method. Have I gotten this right?

Comment: Cant help you without more details